# Parallels "Creating Snapshot" hangup

Tags: mac, freeze, parallels, snapshot

I am using Windows paralles with my mac and I began "creating snapshot" in my VM. But the process won't stop. Now if I startup the VM, I cannot quit parallels and also can't shutdown my computer without a force shutdown. How can I get the VM to stop "creating snapshot"? Let me know if i need to provide more info as Im not too tech savvy.